# Does bce_logits_loss() use ones() and zeros() as targets?

Tags: pytorch

In training Discriminator D(), do we still use target vectors [1,1,1,...] and [0,0,0,...], respectfully, for positive and negative targets for D(), when using bce_logits_loss()?

Intention:

```
import torch
bce_logits_loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
x = torch.ones(1000)*.5
ones = torch.ones(1000)
zeros = torch.zeros(1000)
err1 = bce_logits_loss(x, ones)
err2 = bce_logits_loss(x, zeros)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are training your discriminator with a binary cross entropy then yes you should be using ones and zeros as target. It essentially comes down to a two classifier, output is either zero or one. You can refer to the [PyTorch DCGAN tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) where they use this approach.